# Is there a way to have a formula exclude a specific cell if no data is entered, but still provide an answer based on the other data points provided?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found a formula that allows me to take a date and add years based on a month and day rounding.

Example:

```
Date: 5/26/1955
Years Added: 65
Rounded to next 1/1
Answer: 1/1/21
```

However, I need the formula to be able to exclude the "rounded to next" if no month and day is provided. Additionally, I need for the formula to hide the answer if any of the cells used in the formula are blank.

I have tried using ifblank language, however, it does not seem to work. It could be that I am not writing the formula correctly.

Below is the current formula I am using:

```
=EDATE(DATE(YEAR('AB Policy Review'!D9),MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D39),DAY('AB Policy Review'!D39)),((MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D39)<MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D9))+Percentage!A18)*12)
```

Is there a way to doctor this into the parameters I need?

The current formula works at rounding the date as I need, however, if I keep the cell empty or place a "0" that has the rounding date (example: 6/1) the formula creates an answer of 12/31 of the prior year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the formula IF() and check if cells D9 or D39 and A18 are > 0, and in that case provide one of 2 results, otherwise provide a blank result:

```
IF(AND('AB Policy Review'!D9>0,'AB Policy Review'!D39>0,Percentage!A18>0),
EDATE(DATE(YEAR('AB Policy Review'!D9),MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D39),MAX(1,DAY('AB Policy Review'!D39))),((MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D39)<MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D9))+Percentage!A18)*12),
IF(AND('AB Policy Review'!D9>0,Percentage!A18>0),
EDATE(DATE(YEAR('AB Policy Review'!D9),MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D9),DAY('AB Policy Review'!D9)),Percentage!A18*12),
"")
```

Now there are 3 possible results:

When D9, A18 and D39 are >0, then Day and month are taken from D39.

When D9 and A18 only are >0, then Day and month are taken from D9.

Else result is blank.

Comment: I tried that formula, however, it is still calculating a date where the formula resides when I enter information on D9, but leave D39 blank.
I used 5/4/1950 in D9, left D39 blank, and it is populating 12/31/1950 into where the formula is located.
I need for the formula to do the following:
-If D9 is blank then formula cell is blank
-If D9 has a date, but A18 is blank, then the formula cell should be blank
If D9 has a date, but D39 is blank, and A18 has years, then the formula provides the answer of D9+A18...
Example: 
D9=5/4/1950
D39=blank
A18=65
Formula Cell=5/4/2015

Comment: So you need to get a result if: D9 is not blank OR D39 is not blank. Then let me edit the formula using AND.

Comment: I am still receive the same results.
The formula cell needs to remain blank until 2 of the 3 or all 3 conditions are met.
Either D9 and A18 need data or D9, D39 and A18 need to have values for the formula cell to show a result.
Is this possible?

Comment: You can play with AND and OR to get that done. So, I still fail to understand which conditions need to be met to the formula provide a result.

Comment: So, from your comment above, I guess you only provide a result when D9, A18 and D39 have data? Do you need a result when D9 and A18 have data only?

Comment: Correct. Either D9 and A18 need data for it to calculate or D9, D39, and A18 need data. It is a either or scenario.

Comment: Therefore, you need a result no matter what data is at D39, isn't it? Anyway, I'll update the formula using the 2 cases, so you see how AND and OR works

Comment: It is leaving the formula cell blank, which is great.   However, if I leave D39 blank, it is rounding the result to 12/31, instead of the original date + years.  Result with updated formula:   
D9= 6/3/1950  D39= blank  A18=65  Formula Result=12/31/15  Need result:  D9=6/3/1950  D39=blank  A18=65  Formula Result: 6/3/15  Or  D9=6/3/1950  D39= Jan-1  A18=65  Formula Result:1/1/16

Comment: I see, let's see if the updated formula above works for all your cases

Comment: I am receiving a "there is a problem with this formula" warning. I really appreciate all your help with this. It has truly been a struggle trying to figure out how to get the formula to meet the criteria I am looking for.

Comment: addressed, there was a misplaced ")"

Comment: After playing with this a bit I realized there is an error computing the date if D39 is empty. It is adding an additional year to the calculation.
D9=5/20/1955
D39=blank
A18=65
Formula= 5/20/21
Should equal 5/20/20
Is the "MAX(1,DAY" portion of this formula causing this glitch?

Comment: It might be, try it without it and see what you get

Comment: That does not seem to fix it...should I use the formula you provided and start a new board for it?

Comment: Hold on, if D39 is empty we should remove    MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D39)<MONTH('AB Policy Review'!D9) as well. I've edited, try it now

Comment: I am receiving the following error "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Comment: Edited again, a ")" was misplaced.